# What am I doing wrong in computing this Taylor Series of $f(x) = \frac{1}{4+x^{2}}$ about a = 0?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4+x^{2}}$$

What I did was notice that this is similar to the geometric series:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x^{2} + x^{3} + x^{4} + ....$$

So I altered my original function from:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4 + x^{2}}$$
to:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4(1 - (-\frac{1}{4}x^{2}))}$$
And so it would now look like:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{4(1 - \left(-\frac{1}{4}x^{2}\right))} = 1 + \left(\frac{-1}{4}x^{2}\right) + \left(\frac{-1}{4}x^{2}\right)^{2} + \left(\frac{-1}{4}x^{2}\right)^{3} + \left(\frac{-1}{4}x^{2}\right)^{4} + .... $$ 
now to account for the 4 out front:
$$ = 4\bigg(1 + \left(\frac{-1}{4}x^{2}\right) + \left(\frac{-1}{4}x^{2}\right)^{2} + \left(\frac{-1}{4}x^{2}\right))^{3} + \left(\frac{-1}{4}x^{2}\right))^{4} + ....\bigg) $$

Why is this wrong?
The correct answer is suppose to be:
$$= \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{16}x^2+\frac{1}{64}x^4-\frac{1}{256}x^6+\frac{1}{1024}x^8+\ldots $$

Thank you

Comment: $\sum x^n/n!$ is the exponential series, not the geometric series.

Comment: There was no factor $4$ out front, but instead a factor $\frac14$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thanks! that's what I meant to put, the other computation was the geometric series, just wrote that first part wrong.

Comment: You are right in principle. It can be a very useful substitution to stuff things in the geometric series. But important to remember radii of convergence.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I know this is probably super basic algebra that is messing me up, but why is it $\frac{1}{4}$ and not 4? I thought with the geo-series we replaced everything with the "new" x's we got then distribute what's in the denominator. But what we are supposed to do is distribute what's in the numerator and denominator?

Comment: A real quick way to see your answer is wrong is to say, "What is the value at $x=0$?" $f(0)=\frac{1}{4}$, but your series evaluates to $4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything is perfect, just one thing:

You have

$$ \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\left(-\frac{1}{4} x^2\right)} $$ 
so you need to take the series and multiply by $\frac14$, not $4$

Comment: Why $\frac{1}{4}$ and not 4?

Comment: Because you have $\frac{1}{ab}=\frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{b}$. @yre In this case, $a=4$ and $b=1+x^2/4$.

Comment: because you have a $4$ in the denominator, which means you divide by it, not multiply:
$ \frac{6}{2\cdot 3} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{6}{3} $

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks! I think what I must remember is we have to distribute the entire fraction as one unit $\frac{1}{4}$ not just the denominator 4, I don't know why I was thinking it was just the denominator that got distributed across. Thanks!